# Linker error-Calling function in C++ file from C file

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, linker

I am trying to execute basic code in C and C++ in Linux environment.
I am using eclipse to run it. Current project is created as C project.

All I am trying to do is to call a function from different file in same folder.
I have my main in `sample.c`, In main I would like to call function `sum(int a, int b)` in `A.c`. I was able to run it. But when I rewrite same function sum in `A.cpp`(*a C++ template file*) it throws linker error.

```
gcc  -o "Test"  ./sample.o
```

> ./sample.o: In function
>   main':/home/idtech/workspace/Test/Debug/../sample.c:19: undefined
>   reference to sum' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [Test]
>   Error 1

I need help in calling functions in C++ file from C file in same folder.
Please help me to solve this linker issue.

Thanks

Harsha

Comment: In general it's best to post code snippets to help others diagnose your problem. However I can guess that you need to use `extern "C"`. Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c/1041880#1041880

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ compiler [mangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B) symbol names in order to encode type information. Typically, when writing C++ functions that should be exposed to C code, you'll want to wrap the function in an `extern "C" { ... }` block, like so (or just prefix it with `extern "C"` as @DaoWen pointed out):

*A.cpp:*

```
extern "C" {
    int sum(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

*caller.c:*

```
extern int sum(int a, int b);
...
int main() { sum(42, 4711); }
```

By marking a function as `extern "C"`, you're sacrificing the ability to overload it, because different overloads are distinguishable *only* by their mangled symbol names, and you just requested that mangling be turned off! What it means is that you cannot do this:

```
extern "C" {
    int sum(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
    float sum(float a, float b) { return a+b; } // conflict!
}
```

Comment: If you only have one such function you can just put the `extern "C"` inline with the function signature instead of introducing a new block: `extern "C" int sum(int a, int b) {`

Comment: Upvoted for not only explaining why it doesn't work (mangling), but also the **disadvantage** of the solution (no overloading).